# Allow only api routes (api/*) to access port 80 and 403, redirect the rest to 443

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, http

I currently have my nginx configured for redirecting port 80 to port 443.

```
server {
   listen [::]:443 ssl
   listen 443 ssl;

   root /var/www/my_app/public;

   server_name example.com www.example.com;

   # rest of my main config
}

# Here is port 80 listen
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
}
```

If I comment out the second server chunk and add `listen 80 default_server; listen [::]:80 default_server;` to above chunk, it allows both http and https access.

What I want to achieve is, if url contains `example.com/api/*` don't redirect http to https, but for the rest of the urls, redirect to https.

- example.com/api/login = allow http
- example.com/api/test = allow http
- example.com/api-docs = redirect to https
- example.com/anything = redirect to https

How can I achieve this with nginx? Do I need to have 2 server blocks and move shared logic in a separate file and consider them individually for each port?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following block for port 80 instead of the one you have:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /var/www/my_app/public;

    location /api {
        # API specific directives
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com;
    }
}
```